# Not being able to take proper screenshots

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot

I am currently working on an app which will take screenshot and then email them as an attachment. I want a screenshot of the following "LinearLayout"...

However, something very weird is happening when this function is called. Instead of taking a screenshot of the whole layout, just about 1/10th of the screenshot is taken (like just the half of the first column). Can anyone please suggest what is wrong with the code here?

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/tableview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:weightSum="1" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TableLayout android:padding="5dp" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/TransactionLog"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="Date" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/dateLabel" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="Details" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/detailsLabel" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="Debit" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/debitLabel" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="Credit" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/creditLabel" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="Balance" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/balanceLabel" /> 
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="5 October 2011" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/date1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="CoCoa Shop" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/details1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="123.53" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/debit1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="0.00" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/credit1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="6729.32" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/balance1" /> 
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="4 October 2011" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/date1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="Best Sell" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/details1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="900.53" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/debit1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="0.00" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/credit1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="6729.32" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/balance1" /> 
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="4 October 2011" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/date1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="Deposit" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/details1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="0.00" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/debit1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="9500.00" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/credit1" /> 
            <TextView android:layout_margin="4dip" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" 
                      android:padding="10dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:text="6729.32" 
                      android:layout_width="0dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/balance1" /> 
        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

And here is the JAVA function which is supposed to take the screenshot and save it to a file called "log" in the SD Card.

```
        private void getScreen()
        {
            View content = findViewById(R.id.tableview);
            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            content.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

            content.layout(0, 0, content.getMeasuredWidth(), content.getMeasuredHeight()); 

            content.buildDrawingCache(true);

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getDrawingCache());
            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache

            File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/log.png");

            try 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.close();

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are  content.getMeasuredWidth() and content.getMeasuredHeight() giving you the correct dimensions?

Comment: I am afraid that I dont know how to check that...

Comment: Dump them to the log and see if they make sense?

Comment: what about if you remove these two lines?  content.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),                      MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));              content.layout(0, 0, content.getMeasuredWidth(), content.getMeasuredHeight());

Comment: @user370305 thanks a bunch! I upvoted your comment...Seems like these are the lines which were messing up!

Comment: I write comment as a answer, If you found its help you then plese upvote it, and if its a right for you then please accept as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove these line an try again,

```
content.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)); 
content.layout(0, 0, content.getMeasuredWidth(), content.getMeasuredHeight());
```